# WCF Web Service Client no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, wcf

I'm trying to create a WCF web service with JSON and Consume with Client in ASP .NET
My WCF web server is up and running hosted on IIS, I have checked with browser, getting JSON response.

**Here is Server web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceApp.Service1">
        <endpoint address="../Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

After that I created a Web Application Client in ASP .NET to consume WCF web service.
I have added WCF web service reference in Client, But

> Visual Studio 2012 not updating client web.config

.
I have found few things in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for my client web.config

**Client web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>-->
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webby">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc" name="Service1" binding="webHttpBinding" 
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webby"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

> calling Service from Client

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result;
            string input = tbInput.Text;
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            try
            {
                result = client.GetData(input);
                lbResult.Text = result;
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

But when I tried read from Web service, getting Exception

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc/GetData that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> Inner Exception: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found."}

I suspect its a Configuration issue in my web.config file,, But not sure what is causing this issue.

Thanks,
Ashok

Comment: What happens if you point your browser to  http://localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc?  Do you get the nice WCF status  page?

Comment: yes, I can see response for localhost/WCFService/Service1.svc/data/ashok in JSON.

Comment: if there are answer(s) to your question, mark an answer if you found it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `WebHttpBinding` for your service.So basically that's an `REST` service. So you cannot add `Service Reference` because `REST` services do not expose any metadata and you need to query the resources via `HTTP` verbs like `GET` or `POST` or so.

Try like :

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your endpoint");
var data_to_send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some data");
using (var _temp = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    _temp.Write(data_to_send, 0, data_to_send.Length);
}    

var res = req.GetResponse();
```

Alternatively you can choose:

```
var req = new HttpClient().PostAsync("your url", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("your params")));
```

Also enable a few properties in your `endpointBehavior` to catch more specific exception details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure why I have used webHttpBinding, I just took an example from internet and trying to learn. I tried to change it to basichttpBinding but that leads to other errors.

Comment: maybe you're trying an example for building a `REST` wcf service.Try this solution .

Comment: try this and mark as answer if works.And you have learnt about `REST` services.

Comment: I tried with first one got Protocol voilation Exception, Can you suggest me changes for httpbinding. I want to do it simple add reference way like a beginner

Comment: From the available templates in visual studio under `WCF` - choose `WCF Service Application`.That'll do.

Comment: Amit you are right, I can't user add reference for REST its only for SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

I read more about webHttpBinding, REST found Client for such services cannot be created with Add service reference.

Here is sample code to call WCF Service: ( I found it easy), response is in JSON format, you need to extract it differently (as of now I don't know how to do that)

Thanks to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275279/Developing-WCF-Restful-Services-with-GET-and-POST

```
string url = "http://localhost:50327/Service1.svc/data/"+input; 
                    string strResult = string.Empty;
                    // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
                    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    // set method as post
                    webrequest.Method = "GET";
                    // set content type
                    webrequest.ContentType = "application/json"; //x-www-form-urlencoded”;
                    // declare & read response from service
                    HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
                    // set utf8 encoding
                    Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                    // read response stream from response object
                    StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader
                        (webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
                    // read string from stream data
                    strResult = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
                    // close the stream object
                    loResponseStream.Close();
                    // close the response object
                    webresponse.Close();
                    // assign the final result to text box
                    result = strResult;
                    lbResult.Text = strResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not be always config problem: once I had the same problem but I put to forgot `servicecontract` so service was running on the server but not able to access it.
here are some checkpoints:

1)find your `.svc` file and right click on it and select option view in browser that will give you the exact local `URL`.

2)give you contract parameter a full value e.g. instead of Contract1 add it with full namespace x.y.Contract1

3)check you have put the latest dll on the IIS server and reseted the app pool

4) check **OperationContract** ,**ServiceContract** tags are properly set or not

Comment: this isn't an answer.To make comment(s)/ask questions/clarifications, put comments in the comment section next to the question.

Comment: Buddy I don't have 50 points to put comments and I really want to help you that's why otherwise I know what to do.
and main thing over here is above points solved your problem or not?